# Kivy: Image is centered in FloatLayout only sometimes

Tags: python, kivy

I am getting to know with kivy's manual slowly. I need to centered image in FloatLayout ans I set up size for FloatLayout according to advice: [Kivy: Image sometimes is not centered in BoxLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47912800/kivy-centered-image-in-boxlayout) . Image is now in center FloatLayout sometimes. Position image in center dependes on value of parameter *orientation*. Influence of parameter' value is described here:

1. orientation = 'horizontal' - ---> image is centered
2. orientation = 'vertical'   -----> image isn't centered

Thank You for your help!

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.graphics import Ellipse


Window.size = (300, 300)

class Scene(FloatLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Scene,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size = 300,300

    def create(self):
        img = Image(pos = (0, 0), source = 'grase40.png') # square 40x40pixels
        self.add_widget(img)
        with self.canvas:
            Color=(1,0,0)
            Ellipse(pos = (80,80), size = (40, 40))

class Title(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Title, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation ='vertical'
        self.scene = Scene()
        self.add_widget(self.scene)

        but = Button(text ='hallo', size_hint = (0.2, 1))
        self.add_widget(but)

class SceneApp(App):
    def build(self):
        title = Title()
        title.scene.create()
        return title

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SceneApp().run()
```

Comment: @ EL3PHANTEN: I used part code from Kivy: how to obtain coordinates of FloatLayout center. and I added button. I obtained good result in horizontal arrangement, but with using vertical arrangement image isn't centered. Can You help me?